# ASP.NET Core API Get error: 'EntityEntry<Vehicle>' does not contain a definition

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I migrated my project from ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core, and my post request method now shows an error for all three entries:

> CS1061: 'EntityEntry' does not contain a definition for 'plateno' and no accessible extension method 'plateno' accepting a first argument of type 'EntityEntry' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My code is:-

```cs
nobleappDbContext.vehicles.Add(vehicle).plateno = vehicle.plateno;
nobleappDbContext.vehicles.Add(vehicle).description = vehicle.description;
nobleappDbContext.vehicles.Add(vehicle).status = 1;
               
nobleappDbContext.SaveChanges();
return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Created);
```

Comment: I think I just found the solution, I have to use as ```nobleappDbContext.vehicles.Add(vehicle).Entity.plateno = vehicle.plateno;```

Comment: I will post as answer once confirmed

Comment: Instead, this will be much simple, after you initialize/assign the value to `vehicle`, then `nobleappDbContext.vehicles.Add(vehicle);`

Comment: @Yong Shun How can I add multiple values to vehicle once , instead of adding multiple time? can you please explain?

Comment: Hi @Sulfy you may create a ListObject List<Vehicle> listVehicle = new List<Vehicle> and insert to vehicle data listVehicle.add(vehicle) then you may add it your nobleappDbContext.vehicles.AddRange(listVehicle);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing the `vehicle` for insertion, in which the variable contains the value for `plateno` and `description` properties.

For `status` property, just assign the value to the `vehicle` instance.

In short, the code should be looked as:

```cs
// Initialize & assign value for vehicle 
vehicle.status = 1;

nobleappDbContext.vehicles.Add(vehicle);
               
nobleappDbContext.SaveChanges();
```